# Como trocar a indentação em linha por ponto Vscode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, configuração, indentação

Gostaria de saber se para usar ponto em vez da indentação em line é necessário alguma extensão? No caso acho que seria como ver cada espaço um ponto.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quer por pontos de fato? Ou quer enxergar cada espaço como um ponto?

Comment: Está tendo alguma dificuldade específica? É igual a qualquer editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As linhas você ativa indo em `File > Preferences > Settings` e coloca

```
"editor.renderIndentGuides": false

"editor.renderWhitespace": "all"
```

Comment: No caso eu gostaria de desativar as linhas e ativar essa identação com pontos. Obrigado.

Comment: @Cleytonvinicius então eh so fazer ao contrario, na primeira opção coloca "false" e na segunda coloca "all" isso vai esconder as linhas guie e só mostrar os pontinhos como vc quer. Na editei a resposta para ficar dessa forma